# Category of modules over internal monoid is abelian

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories

I have asked the following question on MSE a few days ago, but without any success.

I am interested in proving the following statement:

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a tensor category. Then the category of modules over a commutative monoid $A$ in $\text{Ind}\mathcal{A}$ is abelian and symmetric monoidal, and every such module is the quotient of a flat module.

Here by 'tensor category' I mean a $k$-linear abelian and rigid symmetric monoidal category whose tensor product is $k$-bilinear and exact in both variables. An $A$-module $M$ is flat if the funtor $-\otimes_A M$ is exact.

I am able to show that this category is symmetric monoidal, but I am having some trouble showing that it is abelian and that every module is the quotient of a flat one. What I found out so far:

- The zero object of $\mathcal{A}$ also is a zero object in $A\textbf{Mod}$ together with the trivial action
- As biproduct of $(M,\rho_M)$ and $(N,\rho_N)$ one can just take the biproduct $M\oplus N$ in $\text{Ind}\mathcal{A}$ with the action $\rho_M \oplus \rho_N$
- I think the following diagrams make the kernel and cokernel of a morphism of $A$-modules (taken in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$) into $A$-modules, hence showing that $A\textbf{Mod}$ has all kernels and cokernels (I think $A\otimes \text{coker} f = \text{coker}(\text{id}\otimes f)$):

[image]

- Since the forgetful functor from $A\textbf{Mod}$ to $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ is a right adjoint of the free functor $X\rightsquigarrow A\otimes X$, it preserves limits and in particular monomorphisms. Therefore a monomorphism in $A\textbf{Mod}$ also is a monomorphism in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ and since this is abelian, it is a kernel there. Then since the underlying objects of kernels in $A\textbf{Mod}$ are kernels in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$, the morphism also is a kernel there.

I have no idea though how to show that every epimorphism is a cokernel in $A\textbf{Mod}$. Also, I do not know how to go about that property with the flatness. I think this is a quite common statement, and yet I could not find a proof anywhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you mimic the usual proof that free modules are flat?  Maybe you need to restrict to free modules *on projective objects*?  Do you not need some kind of “enough projectives” assumption in your definition of tensor category?

Comment: @NoahSnyder Yes, all free modules are flat here. That follows directly from the fact that the tensor product in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ is exact. That in turn is a consequence of $\mathcal{A}$ being rigid.

Comment: So can’t you then just say every module is a quotient of a free module (and hence of a flat one)?

Comment: @NoahSnyder I am not quite sure how to adapt the usual proof that every module is a quotient of a free module to my setting. In particular, since we do not work over Set, there is no canonical way to write $A\otimes M$ as a direct sum of copies of $M$.

Comment: Ah, I see, the point is that you only get for free that it's a subobject of $A \otimes M$ not a quotient?

Comment: @NoahSnyder Yes, subobject works because we have the unit $I\rightarrow A$ of the monoid $A$. But we cannot define something like $\bigotimes_{x\in M} A$, since "$x\in M$" is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, why can't we just use $\rho_M$ as the map $A \otimes M \rightarrow M$ to realize $M$ as a quotient?

Comment: @NoahSnyder You're very right, $\rho$ is a split epi, I totally missed that! Thank you!

Comment: For epis are cokernels, I would have thought that you just take the cokernel of the underlying objects and show that it's also a cokernel in the category of modules.  What's the sticking point?

Comment: @NoahSnyder Well I don't think it is clear that an epimorphism in $A\textbf{Mod}$ also is epic in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$, since the later has more morphisms. For monomorphisms that is easy because the forgetful functor is a right adjoint, but for epis this does not work.

Comment: Epi in Amod implies that the cokernel in Amod is 0, which then means that the cokernel in Ind(A) is 0, which then means it's Epi in Ind(A)?

Comment: @NoahSnyder I was not aware that cokernel zero implies epic in abelian categories, can you give a reference to that?

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ZX

Comment: @NoahSnyder That certainly solves the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, when you get a chance maybe write up a short summary of this as an answer and I’ll upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a summary of the discussion in the comments.

**To the question why $A\textbf{Mod}$ is abelian**: A morphism in an abelian category is monic (resp. epic) if and only if its kernel (resp. cokernel) is zero. Now suppose we are given an epimorphism $f$ in $A\textbf{Mod}$; then its cokernel is zero, and since the underlying object in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ of $\text{coker}(f)$ is the cokernel of the underlying morphism of $f$, we have $\text{coker}(f)= 0$ in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ also. Thus, $f$ is epic in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ and hence a cokernel. By the construction of cokernels in $A\textbf{Mod}$, this shows that $f$ is a cokernel in this category also. The same works for monomorphisms and kernels.

**To the question why every module is the quotient of a flat module**: Because the tensor product in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ is exact, every free $A$-module is flat. By the unit axiom of modules, the composition

$$ M\simeq I\otimes M \xrightarrow{e\otimes \text{id}_M} A\otimes M \xrightarrow{\rho} M$$

must be the identity on $M$ ($e$ is the unit of the monoid $A$), so in particular $\rho$ is split epic, and hence $M$ is a quotient of $A\otimes M$ viewed as free $A$-module.